# Ada container in a Extended tagged type

Tags: oop, generics, ada

I want to had a container in an extended tagged type.
Ex. :

```
type Root is abstract tagged private;

package Queue_Interface
is new Ada.Containers.Synchronized_Queue_Interfaces
  (Element_Type => Ada.Strings.Unbounded.Unbounded_String);

package Queue_Factory
is new Ada.Containers.Bounded_Synchronized_Queues
  (Queue_Interfaces => Queue_Interface,
   Default_Capacity => 50);

type Child is new Root with record
      Trace_Queue : Queue_Factory.Implementation.List_Type(50);
end record;
```

When I try to compile this code I have the following error : "extension of nonlimited type cannot have limited components"

I can't change the declaration of the Root type it's a type in a dependency.
How can I embed a container in a tagged type ?

Comment: If you want a limited component ("limited" prohibits assignment, for a start) in an extended type, you have to make the root type limited too, as in `type Root is abstract tagged limited private;`.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1. Use a non-limited container type.
2. Make your tagged type limited (as Brian suggests in the comments).

Comment: `Bounded_Synchronized_Queues.Queue` is a protected type, i.e limited. So are all the other Queue types.

Comment: I read the question as being about putting a containers in records.

Comment: I meant that `Ada.Containers.Bounded_Synchronized_Queues.Queue` is (a) in the standard library, (b) limited, which contradicts your option 1.

Answer (score 0):

Indirection may be a starting point. Use a pointer to the limited type. If used as a record component and not being itself limited, a pointer does not force the record type to be limited.

```
 package Queue_Interface
 is new Ada.Containers.Synchronized_Queue_Interfaces
    (Element_Type => Ada.Strings.Unbounded.Unbounded_String);

 package Queue_Factory
 is new Ada.Containers.Bounded_Synchronized_Queues
    (Queue_Interfaces => Queue_Interface,
     Default_Capacity => 50);

 type List_Pointer is
     access Queue_Factory.Implementation.List_Type;

 type Child is new Cannot_Change.Root with record
      Trace_Queue : List_Pointer (50);
 end record;
```

It might be a good idea to consider ways of using a type derived from `Ada.Finalization.Controlled` if memory management is an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Do you actually need a standard `Ada.Containers.*.Queue`? because they are implemented as protected types, which are `limited`, and give task safety. If not, you could implement your own Queue in terms of, say, a standard Vector.